# Why odd characters appear when printing large ArrayLists

Tags: java, string, arraylist, string-formatting

I am following a tutorial which partially deals with printing the elements of ArrayLists.  The program runs exactly as I'd expect when dealing with small lists.  However the string formatting ( I believe ) causes some strange results when larger numbers are input.

My code is as follows:

```
public class Theatre {
    private final String theatreName;
    public List<Seat> seats = new ArrayList<>();

    public Theatre(String theatreName, int numRows, int seatsPerRow) {
        this.theatreName = theatreName;

        int lastRow = 'A' + (numRows -1);
        for (char row = 'A'; row <= lastRow; row++) {
            for(int seatNum = 1; seatNum <= seatsPerRow; seatNum++) {
                Seat seat = new Seat(row + String.format("%02d", seatNum));
                seats.add(seat);
            }
        }
    }

    public String getTheatreName() {
        return theatreName;
    }

    public boolean reserveSeat(String seatNumber) {
        int low = 0;
        int high = seats.size()-1;

        while(low <= high) {
            System.out.print(".");
            int mid = (low + high) /2;
            Seat midVal = seats.get(mid);
            int cmp = midVal.getSeatNumber().compareTo(seatNumber);

            if(cmp <0) {
                low = mid + 1;
            } else if(cmp > 0) {
                high = mid -1;
            } else {
                return seats.get(mid).reserve();
            }
        }

            System.out.println("There is no seat " + seatNumber);
            return false;


    }

    // for testing
    public void getSeats() {
        for(Seat seat : seats) {
            System.out.println(seat.getSeatNumber());
        }
    }

    public class Seat implements Comparable<Seat > {
        private final String seatNumber;
        private boolean reserved = false;

        public Seat(String seatNumber) {
            this.seatNumber = seatNumber;
        }

        public boolean reserve() {
            if(!this.reserved) {
                this.reserved = true;
                System.out.println("Seat " + seatNumber + " reserved");
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public boolean cancel() {
            if(this.reserved) {
                this.reserved = false;
                System.out.println("Reservation of seat " + seatNumber + " cancelled");
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public String getSeatNumber() {
            return seatNumber;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Seat seat) {
            // returns integer greater than 0 if greater than, less than if less than, 0 if equal
            return this.seatNumber.compareTo(seat.getSeatNumber());
        }
    }
```

With a Main method class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Theatre theatre = new Theatre("Olympian", 800, 12);
        List<Theatre.Seat> seatCopy = new ArrayList<>(theatre.seats); // shallow copy, contains references to all
                                                                        // elements of both lists, original and copy
        printList(seatCopy);


        seatCopy.get(1).reserve();
        if (theatre.reserveSeat("A02")) {
            System.out.println("Please pay for A02");
        } else {
            System.out.println("seat already reserved");
        }

        // see that they are clearly two separate array lists
        Collections.reverse(seatCopy);
        System.out.println("Printing seat copy");
        printList(seatCopy);
        System.out.println("Printing theatre.seats");
        printList(theatre.seats);
        System.out.println("Shuffling seatCopy");
        Collections.shuffle(seatCopy);
        printList(seatCopy);

    }

    public static void printList(List<Theatre.Seat> list) {
        for (Theatre.Seat seat : list) {
            System.out.print(" " + seat.getSeatNumber());
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("===============================");
    }

}
```

The output (I only quote enough to see ) is:

```
12 ͠11 ͠10 ͠09 ͠08 ͠07 ͠06 ͠05 ͠04 ͠03 ͠02 ͠01 ͟12 ͟
===============================
Printing theatre.seats
A01 A02 A03 A04 A05 A06 A07 A08 A09 A10
===============================
===============================
 Shuffling seatCopy
V07 Ý11 11 ű05 Ú02 ̄06 ̓01 ŕ12 ȣ03 Ǔ05 S07
```

I am aware that I run out of alphabetical characters and that the formatting in this line:

```
Seat seat = new Seat(row + String.format("%02d", seatNum));
```

is intended only to deal with seats of the format "X##".

What I want to understand is specificallty why the odd characters appear ( the "~" and "'", etc. ).  Obviously, the formatting is inappropriate.  But why does it produce specifically this output?

Thank you for your help, 
Marc

Answer (score 3):

You said it yourself. You're running out of alphabetical characters. In fact, you're running out of ASCII characters altogether. From this line:

```java
for (char row = 'A'; row <= lastRow; row++)
```

What you are doing is starting the row letters from 'A' and continuing across the Unicode character set. So, with more than 26 rows, you start getting symbols like `~`, and with enough rows, you leave ASCII altogether and start getting weird row letters like Ý.

If you don't want this to happen, you'll need to ditch the for loop and come up with an entirely different (and more complex) way of assigning row labels.

Comment: Right, Thank you.  I was just wondering why the weird row letters appear as they do and not otherwise.

Comment: @MarcHolman Java (like JavaScript, .NET, VB4, T-SQL, …) uses the UTF-16 encoding of the [Unicode character set](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html).